# What strategy can I use to only load part of my code to github?

Tags: javascript, git, github

I use the push to deploy pattern.  However, when I push I also want to update my my github.

This would be easy for me to do, however I only want my github account to have a certain set of files.  In this case all my javascript files.

What is a strategy I could use to do this?  Is this difficult, I would imagine this is a common thing people would want to do.

Answer (score 1):

Use the *.gitignore* file ([here](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore) the documentation) to exclude all the files and directories you don't want to push to the remote repository.

Otherwise, put your JavaScript files in a subdirectory and initialize/use only that directory as a *git repository*.

Again, create two repository and add one of them as a *submodule* of the other, thus put there you JavaScript files and set the remote on github.

It mainly depends on how your project is structured, but there are several solutions to do that.

Comment: What? You can freely put a `.gitignore` file in any directory. It was due maybe to what you wrote in those files.

Comment: right ... but the .gitignore will be applied to both remote repositories.

Comment: Reading the documentation you linked is a good point from which to start. :-)

Comment: @cadegalt your question doesn't mention wanting to have different ignored files on different remotes. That's just not how git works; the code across all remotes should be the same. You could potentially have a build step that puts all the files you want to deploy into a sub directory, then have that directory be a separate repo or a submodule.

Comment: @Coding - exactly ... multiple .gitignores does not work so it should not be part of the answer.  That being said the question comes down to comparing a repo inside a repo vs. a sub-module.